# CSS: select li elements with especific class

Tags: html, css

In a tutorial i see:

Combine the Class Selector

```
A.className
```

So:

`ul.important` will select all `<ul>` elements that have `class="important"`

======

I've tried:

```
ul.seccion:link {
    color: white;
}
```

and:

```
a.seccion:link {
    color: white;
}
```

to set the initial colors of the links in my main nav to white. But without success. What i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```css
a.seccion:link {
    color: white;
}
    
a:link {
    color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}


a:visited {
    color: #007ACC;
}


a:hover {
    color: #4DB8FF;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="yo.png">
        <h1 class="oo">omargonzalesdiaz.com</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menusuperior">
                <li class="seccion"><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="seccion"><a href="/events">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="seccion"><a href="/events">Dashboards</a></li>
                <li class="seccion"><a href="/events">Contáctame</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is on the li and not the anchor tag.  Try this:

```
    li.seccion a:link{   }
```

Comment: Works. But why `li.seccion:link` would not be right? May you give a deeper explanation?

Comment: The .seccion class is attached to the li element, not the anchor element.  That is why you need li.seccion.  The a:link is specifically an anchor element attribute.  Since list elements dont have href link attributes, li:link does not make any sense.  If you had placed a class inside the anchor, lets say myAnchor, then a.myAnchor:link would work.

Comment: Here is a crash course in CSS:  The li.seccion says "find any li element with a class .seccion".  What li.seccion a  does is says "find any a element inside of an li element with class seccion.  What li.seccion a:link does is "find any a element inside of an li element with class seccion, and style the link this way...."

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition and Usage**
>   The :link selector is used to select unvisited links.
>
> Note: The :link selector does not style links you have already visited.

**[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp)** is the source of the information above.

You have just to separate you selctors, like the following code :

```
ul .seccion :link {
    background-color: white;
}
```

First you have to separate the `.secccion` and `ul` because the both without space separation means select the `ul` that have class `seccion`, same you have to separate the class `.seccion` and `:link` because otherwise it will considered like same element that is anchor and have class `seccion`.

**Code:**

```css
a.seccion:link {
    color: white;
}
body{
    background-color:blue;
}

ul .seccion a {
    background-color: white;
}

a:link {
    color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}


a:visited {
    color: #007ACC;
}


a:hover {
    color: #4DB8FF;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="yo.png">
    <h1 class="oo">omargonzalesdiaz.com</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul id="menusuperior">
            <li class="seccion"><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="seccion"><a href="/events">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="seccion"><a href="/events">Dashboards</a></li>
            <li class="seccion"><a href="/events">Contáctame</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: the code does not reflect what your suggestion says. There is no separation.

Comment: You can see the spaces here " ul .seccion :link" this is separation that i mean.

Comment: There's many solutions for your case i think my answer provide the closest solution to what you requested in your question but i don't know why you didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations:

- `li.seccion:link` will try to select LI elements that have class `seccion` **and** are anchor `a` elements. Obviously, this selector will match nothing because `<li>` can't be `<a>` at the same time.
- `li.seccion :link` (note, the space) selects unvisited anchor `<a>` tags descendants of the `li` element with the class `seccion`.

Comment: Your example does not work. It should be il instead of ul, because the class is in the il not in ul element.